# Prolog, issues with base case failing

Tags: recursion, search, prolog

I'm currently writing a prolog A* search function, and ran into an issue with one of my queries. So I decided to manually test the base case, as that's where the trace was failing.

```
addAChild([Child],[],[Child]):-
   write(woo empty).
```

I manually ran:

```
addAChild([c(1,1,p(1,2)),[]],[],A).
```

but it just fails.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[Child]` (a 1-element list) cannot unify with `[c(1,1,p(1,2)),[]]` (a 2-elements list).

That's why it is failing.

You can manually test in the interactive interpreter that those two terms fail to unify:

```
?- addAChild([Child],[],[Child]) = addAChild([c(1,1,p(1,2)),[]],[],A).
false.
```

and then you can inspect recursively which part is failing.

The term name (`addAChild`) and the arity (3) is the same, so we can rule off this issue.

Then proceed to unify each argument:

```
?- [Child] = A.
A = [Child].

?- [] = [].
true.

?- [Child] = [c(1,1,p(1,2)),[]].
false.
```

Comment: but say instead it was defined such that (Child,[],Child) were the desired inputs, would it still care about the format of the two, in regards to using the second as a way to dump output?

Comment: in that form would succeed to unify, provided the first argument can unify with the third (in your example, yes, because the third argument `A` is a free variable).

Comment: That was what prompted me to try what I submitted in my question, in that format it is failing as well, and I cannot understand why.

Comment: Sorry my bad, a write statement immediately following it seemed to be making it fail. Thank you for your answer.